# Using ValueRange and logscale=TRUE in dygraphs in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

I've got a bit of a problem using both the ValueRange and logscale options for a dygraph in R. If I only use logscale=TRUE (in which case I comment out the ValueRange option), the graph cuts off at an upper bound of 100000, while my data goes all the way to nearly 1800000. 
However, if I add the ValueRange to be the correct upper bound, I get an empty plot and logscale doesn't work. Please find my code below and snippets of the plots as well.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you

```
ass_vs_NGDP <- dygraph(chart_ratio, main="Total Assets and NGDP", ylab="In £mn") %>%

dyAxis("y", valueRange=c(0, 180000)) 

for (j in c(1:nrow(merged_indep))) {
ass_vs_NGDP <- ass_vs_NGDP %>%   
dyAnnotation(merged_indep$yearonly[j],     
text=merged_indep$Text[j], tooltip = merged_indep$Country[j]) 
}

dyOptions(ass_vs_NGDP ,logscale=TRUE)
```

[image: Correct upperbound- logscale doesn't work]
[image: Logscale with incorrect upper bound]

Comment: What if you set the `valueRange` to `(1, 180000)` instead of `(0, 180000)`? You may be having trouble because `log(0) = -Infinity`.

Comment: That did it. Amazing. Thank you very much.